# Excel Add Rows to All Tables and Insert Data in All of Them

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project and I need to find a way to add a row of data to all the tables in the worksheet "Staff" and in these new rows some data has to be input that has to be input in all the new rows that have been made.

Currently I got this code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim newrow As ListRow

Set ws = ActiveSheet
myValue_1 = InputBox("What Month?")
myValue_2 = InputBox("Fill in name", "Name Employee")
myValue_3 = InputBox("Fill in birth date", "Birth Date Employee")
myValue_4 = InputBox("Fill in BSN", "BSN Employee")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(myValue_1)

Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
With newrow
    .Range(1) = myValue_2
    .Range(2) = myValue_3
    .Range(3) = myValue_4
End With

End Sub
```

This code however looks for specific tables (which have month names, january, february, etc.). So with this code I am able to fill in data in 1 specific table, but I want to be able to get this data into each table that is in the worksheet "Staff".

Can someone help me out here?

Kind regards,

Comment: `For each tbl in Worksheets("Staff").ListObjects`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment BigBen. Unfortuntatley I do not have much experience with VBA and I am unsure where to place this line. Currently I placed it above Set NewRow=tbl.ListRows.Add, but I keep getting errors when I try this and change things like "Object Required" and "expect next". I am unsure how to tackle this. Could you help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through all the tables in the worksheet:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim newrow As ListRow

    myValue_2 = InputBox("Fill in name", "Name Employee")
    myValue_3 = InputBox("Fill in birth date", "Birth Date Employee")
    myValue_4 = InputBox("Fill in BSN", "BSN Employee")

    For Each tbl in Worksheets("Staff").ListObjects
        Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

        With newrow
            .Range(1) = myValue_2
            .Range(2) = myValue_3
            .Range(3) = myValue_4 
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BigBen I got it working with the following code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim NewRow As ListRow

myValue_2 = InputBox("Fill in name", "Name Employee")
myValue_3 = InputBox("Fill in birth date", "Birth Date Employee")
myValue_4 = InputBox("Fill in BSN", "BSN Employee")

For Each tbl In Worksheets("Staff").ListObjects
    Set NewRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    With NewRow
        .Range(1) = myValue_2
        .Range(2) = myValue_3
        .Range(3) = myValue_4
    End With
Next tbl
End Sub
```